# Return a promise from an executor function?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Trying to interact with a JS API, but it fails when run by a Grunt task; I think my logic is confused. My steps:

- get tokens from file, check them (`check_tokens`)
- if they are old - refresh them (`refresh_tokens`)
- call API to refresh, if fails - get new ones (`authorize_with_api`) <- this is the issue
- from `authorize_with_api` reject with error or resolve with tokens

Currently the Grunt task reports an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and never completes. If I comment out the call to `authorize_with_api` it then exits properly with an error, and I get my topmost `caught error!` message printed.

Why can't I return a promise out of an executor function? What's wrong with my logic?

```
/* global sdk, config, tokens */
return getTokens().then((p_tokens) => {
    tokens = p_tokens;
    return check_tokens(tokens);
}).then((tokens) => {
    console.log('then() is called!');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('caught error!', err);
}); 

function check_tokens(tokens) {
    if(are_old(tokens)) { // returns true
        return refresh_tokens(tokens);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(tokens);
}

function refresh_tokens(tokens) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sdk.refreshTokens(tokens.refresh_token, function(err, new_tokens) {
            if(err) {
                if(error.code === 'invalid_grant') {
                    return authorize_with_api();
                }
                reject('refreshTokens failed');
            } else if(newTokens) {
                resolve(new_tokens);
            } 
        });
    });
}

function authorize_with_api() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sdk.getTokens(config.auth_code, function(err, tokens) {
            if(err) {
                reject('getTokens failed');
            } else if(tokens) {
                resolve(tokens);
            } 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `tokens` seems to be undefined inside `authorize_with_api `, did you mean to pass it in? Showing your gulp task that calls this may be helpful

Comment: Please avoid doing your own promisification. Libraries have been written to solve this task, use one of them. For example, bluebird can do it for you. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Comment: @Tomalak Can you explain further? The OP is using native Promises?

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not well-versed in this - can you point out where am I "promisifying" now - by wrapping SDK calls into Promises? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Turning a non-promise API into a promise API is not trivial, mistakes are easily made (in this case, the OP forgot to use try/catch). I'm not saying the OP should switch to bluebird, I'm saying the OP should use a tested library that does the promisification.

Comment: @Tomalak Are you saying the error is because of the undefined  variable (try catch would help)? Montrealist: you haven't answered my comment about the undefined variable

Comment: @JuanMendes tokens would exist inside the callback from `sdk.getTokens`; if not - I reject, unless this is incorrect and I should `throw` an error instead.

Comment: @montrealist Well, you edited the question. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Returning from a Promise constructor (or any function within it) does not resolve a promise:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  sdk.refreshTokens(..., function(err, new_tokens) {
    if(error.code === 'invalid_grant') {
      return authorize_with_api();
    } // ^--- this will not chain to the promise being created.
```

Even if you didn't have the return from the `sdk.refreshTokens` callback and instead had a direct `return authorize_with_api()` without the callback, the result would still not get chained.

To resolve a promise, you cannot return from its constructor but must explicitly call one of the given callbacks (resolve/reject) instead:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  sdk.refreshTokens(..., function(err, new_tokens) {
    if(error.code === 'invalid_grant') {
      resolve(authorize_with_api());
    } // ^--- must call resolve here
```

Resolving a promise actually handles rejection as well so no matter if `authorize_with_api` resolves or rejects, the state will propagate up the chain accordingly.

My suggestion is to still keep the `return` statement to maintain the intended visual semantics of the `if` branch conditioning an early return but the code will work without it because [Promises can only be resolved once](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description) and all further calls to `reject`/`resolve` are ignored.

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  sdk.refreshTokens(..., function(err, new_tokens) {
    if(error.code === 'invalid_grant') {
      return resolve(authorize_with_api());
    } // ^--- should still return here for readability - clean logic purposes
    reject('refreshTokens failed'); // this will be ignored if the above `resolve` gets called first, no matter if you have the `return` statement
```

Examples:

```js
function success() {
  return Promise.resolve('success');
}

function error() {
  return Promise.reject('error');
}

function alwaysPending() {
  return new Promise(() => {
    return success();
  });
}

function resolves() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(success());
  });
}

function rejects() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(error());
  });
}

alwaysPending().then(console.log); // doesn't log anything 
resolves().then(console.log);
rejects().catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! _removes hat_

Comment: Glad to help out mate :)

Comment: Notice that he doesn't even `return` from the `Promise` executor function, but from an asynchronous callback somewhere inside that.

Answer (score 1):

Just write else statement of last if:

```
function authorize_with_api() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sdk.getTokens(config.auth_code, function(err, tokens) {
            if(err) {
                reject('getTokens failed');
            } else if(tokens) {
                resolve(tokens);
            } else {
                reject('tokens == undefined && err == undefined');
            }
        });
    });
}
```